# java class design to handle future changes

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

If a received object [json or excel file] has 10 fields. From the 10 fields, 4 are stable while 6 fields and their names are getting changed. There could be removal of fields from the given 6 fields and there could be new fields added. How to design classes or handle such cases with minimal changes in future

Comment: maybe just use a map.

Comment: A map if accessed by child can be modified. I dont want anybody to change stable field name.

Comment: you can make it an immutable map

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume in example you have user info represented in your file. When you have stable and unstable fields simple put away unstable data to different class.

```
class User {
       String name;
       String surname;
       String gender;
       Integer age;
       Metadata metadata;

     //constructor that receive all this data

 }

class Metadata {
//here fields that's you change in future but
//class User don't need to know about this changes
}
```

Comment: Do you mean to add base class with stable fields and extend it with class such that child class has unstable field?

Comment: @user3401717 no, in my answer User and Metadata is two different classes, no extensions need here